# How to configure AWS CloudFront to use secured websocket through custom port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have been trying to configure my AWS cloudfront to have the possibility to use websocket wss from client to server using the port 3200.

I have an EC2 instance running ubuntu, on it I have:

1. On the ubuntu :

- Node running the websocket server on port 3200
- the react client served on port 80 thanks to Nginx

2. On AWS:

- security group configured for HTTPS

I have a domain name from AWS and a SSL certificate from AWS as well.

I configure cloudfront:

1. To redirect HTTP request to HTTPS on the ec2 instance using the certificate (this is working)
2. I tried to redirect HTTPS port 3200 to ec2 instance as well, I added headers for WebScoket (example: Sec-WebSocket-Version) in the origin request policy.

Finally I have configured Route 53 :

1. Type A to my cloudfront
2. CNAME for the certificate

I have tried plenty of tweaks on the cloudfront configuration:

- allowing both HTTP and HTTPS
- changing origin path or port

Unfortunately when I try to call my server I run on timeout.

I was also checking the load balancer and API Gateway, but if there is a way of doing it only with Cloudfront I would rather not use those.

Is there anything I'm missing or I misunderstand ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up with Cloudfront as I think it not configurable the way I want it.
So I went for an Application Load Balancer, there I could properly set what I desired.